# Lie Groups and Lie Algebra for Nonlinear System Dynamics

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, nonlinear-system

I have a background in machine learning and control theory. Lately, I shifted my focus towards nonlinear systems. I am interested in rigorous mathematical analysis, stability, and control of nonlinear dynamical systems.

I have a solid mathematical background in measure theory, functional analysis, and ergodic theory.

To be more specific, I am looking for some reference that:

1. Introduces Lie Groups and Lie Algebra.
2. Gives a special treatment for their applications in nonlinear systems.

I am citing the following article as a motivation

$[1]$ Chein-Shan Liu,
A Lie-group DSO(n) method for nonlinear dynamical systems,
Applied Mathematics Letters,
Volume 26, Issue 7,
2013,
Pages 710-717,
ISSN 0893-9659,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2013.01.012.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965913000530)

Comment: Check Sastry's book on nonlinear systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in control aspects of nonlinear systems you could have a look into the **second edition** of Sontag's *"Mathematical Control Theory"* (1998): in [Chapter 4](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0577-7_4) Sontag treats non-linear control systems and how to study them via Lie theory.

Admittedly, this book is not an introduction to Lie groups & Lie algebras but I think it very much satisfies your second criterion which is why I felt inclined to mention it here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommended reference, I truly appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is Peter Olver's *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations* (*Graduate Texts in Mathematics* **107**, Springer-Verlag, 1986).

Answer (score 2):

The book "Nonlinear Dynamical Control Systems" by Henk Nijmeijer and Arjan van der Schaft use these concepts in the context of control. This might be a useful reference for you as well, next to the given ones.

link: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2101-0

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommended reference, I truly appreciate it. I will definitely rely on it

Answer (score 2):

Another good reference is

> Francesco Bullo and Andrew Lewis, [Geometric Control of Mechanical Systems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4899-7276-7) (2005).

- For the first part of your question, see in particular Chapter 5 (*Lie groups, systems on groups, and symmetries*) including Section 5.2 (*Lie groups and Lie algebras*).
- For the second part of your question, see Chapter 6 (*Stability*) and Chapter 7 (*Controllability*).